# PyInstaller not accepting hidden libraries

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pysimplegui, joblib

I have a PySimpleGUI application which uses Joblib .pkl.pkl file to access a CNN model. I tried to convert this .py file to .exe using pyinstaller by the command:

```
    pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --windowed --icon "icon.ico" --add-data "icon.ico;." --add-data "finalmodel.pkl.pkl;."  main.py
```

Converts file to exe well, but then,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 658, in load
  File "joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 577, in _unpickle
  File "pickle.py", line 1213, in load
  File "pickle.py", line 1538, in load_stack_global
  File "pickle.py", line 1580, in find_class
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
```

Can I do something that somehow includes all hidden imports?

Comment: yes... add the hidden imports explicityl with --hidden-import

Comment: How do I know what all libraries I have to add there?